# too much apache processes running and consume memory

Tags: apache-2.4, memory-usage

I've an instance of type c5d.xlarge on aws with centos 7 with 8GB of RAM. I'm running a magento storefront on it. Magento version is 2.7.1 . Now the problem is the memory usage is 74% and it gets out of memory sometimes, although storefront not public for users yet.

And when I've checked the processes I've found that about 100 processes are for apache, All of them has the same command of `/usr/sbin/httpd Dforeground` but with different usage of memory which range from 600MB to 900MB.

The question is why all those processes are running and how to choose the best processes to kill and keep storefront running?

**Note1:**: CPU usage is 0%, it get in use when I open the storefront and start send requests.

**Note2:** I've checked for MPM it's `prefork` but when I open `httdp.conf` I cannot find `prefork` module or other module for MPM inside it

Comment: Magento may require a significant amount of tuning in order to work well. It is a rather heavy piece of software. We have a site dedicated to [Magento.se] where you may be able to get better help than you would here.